# Unable to list the dates from filtered datagridview into combobox

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, rowfilter

My `dataGridView_flaggedComments` is filled with some original comments.

I then use `comboBox_stockIndex_SelectedIndexChanged` function to filter the comments in `dataGridView_flaggedComments` according to `Tickers_Ticker_ID`.

Next, with the filtered comments, I want to list out the comments' dates to `comboBox_stockDates`, using `PopulateStockDatesIndex()` function.

However, `PopulateStockDatesIndex()` function is listing all the dates (of the original non-filtered comments). How can I only list the dates that come from the filtered comments?

My code as below. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

```
private void comboBox_stockIndex_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataRow db in LoadTickers().Rows)
    {
        if (comboBox_stockIndex.SelectedItem.ToString() == db["Symbol"].ToString())
        {
            (dataGridView_flaggedComments.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Tickers_Ticker_ID = '{0}'", db["Ticker_ID"].ToString());
        }
    }

    PopulateStockDatesIndex();
}


private void PopulateStockDatesIndex()
{
    comboBox_stockDates.Items.Clear();
    comboBox_stockDates.Items.Add("Choose to Filter");
    comboBox_stockDates.FormatString = "dd-MM-yyyy";
    DataTable dt_filterDate = (DataTable)(dataGridView_flaggedComments.DataSource);
    foreach (DataRow row in dt_filterDate.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView_flaggedComments.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView_flaggedComments.Rows[i].Cells["Comments_Date"].Value.ToString() != "")
            {
                string date = row.Field<DateTime>(1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                if (!comboBox_stockDates.Items.Contains(date))
                {
                    comboBox_stockDates.Items.Add(date);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P/S: I tried my best to explain my question and put my question into proper formatting and I have also done quite some research regarding this, kindly don't downvote me and let me know where I did wrongly or if my question is not clear enough. I apologise if there are similar questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void PopulateStockDatesIndex()
{
    comboBox_stockDates.Items.Clear();
    comboBox_stockDates.Items.Add("Choose to Filter");

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView_flaggedComments.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView_flaggedComments.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView_flaggedComments.Rows[i].Cells["Comments_Date"].Value.ToString() != "")
            {
                string str = dataGridView_flaggedComments.Rows[i].Cells["Comments_Date"].Value.ToString();
                DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"));
                if (!comboBox_stockDates.Items.Contains(date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")))
                {
                    comboBox_stockDates.Items.Add(date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));

                }
                comboBox_stockDates.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you applied the filter beforehand, you set the filter on the `DataView`, not the actual `DataTable`. When you access the data in the datatable in `PopulateStockDatesIndex()`, you are accessing the unfiltered `DataTable` and not the view. Try to change to

```
private void comboBox_stockIndex_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     foreach (DataRow db in LoadTickers().Rows)
     {
        if (comboBox_stockIndex.SelectedItem.ToString() == db["Symbol"].ToString())
        {
             (dataGridView_flaggedComments.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Tickers_Ticker_ID = '{0}'", db["Ticker_ID"].ToString());
        }
     }

     PopulateStockDatesIndex((dataGridView_flaggedComments.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter);
}

private void PopulateStockDatesIndex(string rowFilter)
{
  comboBox_stockDates.Items.Clear();
  comboBox_stockDates.Items.Add("Choose to Filter");
  comboBox_stockDates.FormatString = "dd-MM-yyyy";
  DataTable dt_filterDate = (DataTable)(dataGridView_flaggedComments.DataSource);
  dt_filterDate.DefaultView.RowFilter = rowFilter;

  foreach (DataRow row in dt_filterDate.Rows)
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView_flaggedComments.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
      {
          if (dataGridView_flaggedComments.Rows[i].Cells["Comments_Date"].Value.ToString() != "")
          {
              string date = row.Field<DateTime>(1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
              if (!comboBox_stockDates.Items.Contains(date))
              {
                  comboBox_stockDates.Items.Add(date);
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

}

Comment: Hi Bryan, first line is givingme error at `DefaultView`, and in second line `db` is not accessible.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the DataRow not being accessible. I updated the answer to reflect a different solution.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your help, but it wasn't quite what I want (doesn't really work in my case). I've figured it out the answer with the help of a chatter in chatroom :)